# Using foreach in a function definition vs. using foreach to write to a file

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I'm having difficulty parallelizing R for optimizing the speed of function calls when writing to a file. The function is simple, but the files it creates are massive, and they take an unreasonable amount of time. I've been using profvis to visualize the where the time is going, and it appears that the suspects are in the cat statement at the end of the function, and in the capture step when writing to the output file. I've included a simplified, small, reproducible example scrip below, but the actual files are massive and I'm running them on a supercomputing cluster. Running the scrip in parallel as written does not grant me any speed increase, but I'm at a loss as to how to structure the foreach statement so that it's actually capturing each iteration of the function in parallel. Putting foreach in the function itself gives me issues with the order (instead of header, base pares, header, base pairs etc. it appends them randomly- however they happened to have come off whichever core they were running on) and putting it in the capture.output line, does not actually seem to do anything.

Intended output:

```
ACCTTCGAA
1321:1007
GGGTCAATA
1258:1115
GGGCCTACG
1335:1642
ATCATCGCC
1547:1735
TCTCAACGA
1518:1935
TTGTGTTCT
1352:1828
CCTTTCGGC
1403:1162
ACAATTCGC
```

Reproducible example script:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)


#create cluster with desired number of cores
cl <- makeCluster(20)

# Register cluster
registerDoParallel(cl)

#create example data
bps <- replicate(10,paste(sample(size = 30, x = c("A","C","G","T"), replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
true_false <- replicate(10,paste(sample(size = 1, x = c("T","F"), replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
my.df<- data.frame(bps, true_false) 


#create function to make unique Header
  Header = function(){
    header = c(sample(1000:2000, 1), ":", sample(1000:2000, 1))
    paste(header, collapse="")
  }


#assemble reads:
  make_file <- function(df) { 
    bps  <- NULL 
    fragment <- seq(from=1, to=(nrow(df)))
    first.9<- seq(from=1, to=9)
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      header <- Header()
      fragment[i] <- df[i,1]
      first.9 <- substring(fragment,1,9)
      bps[i] <- cat(header, first.9[i], sep = "\n")
    }
    return(bps)
  }



  #regular capture
capture.output(make_file(df = my.df), file = "myfile1.txt", append = TRUE)

  #foreach capture 
foreach(x=(capture.output(make_file(df = my.df), file = "myfile2.txt", append = TRUE))) %dopar% {x}
```

Comment: Hi @user8173816 if my answer helped with your issue please consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. It lets the community know that it worked and that your issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` already provides looping behavior, and tries to assemble the output (which you can specify).

Your data:

```
bps <- replicate(10,paste(sample(size = 30, x = c("A","C","G","T"), replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
true_false <- replicate(10,paste(sample(size = 1, x = c("T","F"), replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
my.df<- data.frame(bps, true_false)
```

New code:

```
library(readr)
library(iterators)
library(foreach)

newfile <- foreach(i=iter(my.df,by="row"), .combine="rbind") %do% { as.data.frame(rbind(Header(), substring(i$bps,1,9))) }
write_tsv(newfile, "C:/temp/temp.txt", append=F, col_names=F)
```

In each `loop` of `foreach`, iterate through `my.df` by row. Then `%do%` the following: `rbind` `Header()` and `substring...`, then turn into `data.frame`. Finally, `.combine` the output with `rbind`. This produces a single column data frame. Write to output file with `write_tsv...`.

Output:

```
          V1
1  1054:1658
2  GACCACTCC
3  1578:1988
4  CAAACGGCT
5  1604:1065
```

**------parallelize--------**

To parallelize, simply replace `%do%` with `%dopar%`. Depending on how many entries you have, `%do%` may actually be faster.

Comment: Thanks @Chi Pak, it took me a while to get this working with the actual (much more complex) function, but it seems to be woking on the small test sets- I seem to be running into memory issues running the script on the actual data on the cluster.

Comment: When running into memory issues, you can either: A) write each line immediately to file (that is, don't assemble into large R structure) or B) break up your input file into small batches. You'll need to post a new question if you want more specific help.